# Spring DefaultSftpSessionFactory cannot connect

Tags: spring, sftp

I can connect to a stfp server using:

**sftp root@44.333.22.1**

However when I configure Spring like this:

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="44.333.22.1"/>
    <property name="user" value="root"/>
    <property name="port" value="22"/>
</bean>
```

I get the following:

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: either a password or a private key is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:334)
    ... 38 more**

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missisng the private key:

```
<property name="privateKey" value="classpath:id_rsa"/>
```